# Spring - Allow only 1 post request to the endpoint per second

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, stripe-payments

Let's say I have exposed POST endpoint like this. There might be half a second delay when sending request to Stripe, and during that time, requests to my endpoint will generate more of requests to stripe.

```
@PostMapping("/customer/create")
@ResponseBody
public void createCustomer() {
    stripeService.createCustomerForAccount();
}
```

The problem is that someone can fire 50 requests and it will create 50 customers. How to prevent it? My idea is to limit user (his session,IP or whatever) so he can only fire 1 request in 1 second to that endpoint. Is it possible? Maybe set some boolean to true until it finishes, but how should I go about that to not affect other users?

Comment: What problems are you trying to solve exactly? If I understand correctly, you don't want to create multiple stripe accounts for the same user. Is that right? So that doesn't have anything to do with request rate limiting. And stripe itself should already do that, and return an error if you try to create an account that already exists, shouldn't it? So just return that error from your own service. If stripe doesn't, then just store the fact that you've already asked to create the customer at the first request, and return a error to the subsequent ones.

Comment: @JBNizet that Stripe is just an example. It creates more of them, but it doesn't matter. I need to lock user out of sending more requests to the endpoint until it processes the previous one.

Comment: I amended my comment. That's not an effective way of doing. What you need to do is return an error for the subsequent requests, because the first one has stored, in the database, the fact that you're already being creating a stripe account for that user. If you have so many users asking for 50 requests, you also have an ergonomy problem. Make it clear, on the screen, that the request is being processed. Disable the submit button. Show a progress spinner.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, of course that I have disabled the button. But that still leaves the app vulnerable to attacks. Should I store a boolean in session and deny all the request until boolean is set to false when the initial one finished?

Comment: Rate limiting won't prevent an attacker to create 50 accounts. It will just take 50 seconds instead of 2. Again, store the fact that the account is being created at the first request, and return an error for the subsequent ones.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to prevent an attack that is not clearly the way to go, you may review incorporate in your application captchas i.e example [google one](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/).